# Programmatically added button crashing the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i press my button the app crashes. Happens even when I create the button programmatically or try and add one through the XIB for the class where I need the button.

I enabled Zombies and the debug msg I get from the console is :

2010-10-27 00:47:28.643 CarTrawler[1537:207] *** -[ReceiptView performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x76cb700

But the button is added to the view. So I don't understand what the problem is.  The class represents a receipt so it gets called depending on how many receipts there are in the app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.refLabel.text = theBooking.confID;
self.carTypeLabel.text = theBooking.vehMakeModelName;
//self.amountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"€22.00"];
self.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", 
    theBooking.locationName, theBooking.locationAddress];
self.numberLabel.text = theBooking.locationPhoneNumber;

self.dateTimeLabel.text = theBooking.puDateTime;
self.doDateTimeLabel.text = theBooking.doDateTime;
DLog(@"Dropoff date time label is %@", theBooking.doDateTime);

CTTableViewAsyncImageView *thisImage = [[[CTTableViewAsyncImageView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 40.0)] autorelease];
[vendorImage addSubview:thisImage];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theBooking.vehPictureUrl];
[thisImage loadImageFromURL:url];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
[button setTitle:@"Email!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)   
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];

}


-(void)buttonPressed {
NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
}
```

Can anybody please explain to me what it is that I have overlooked?

Comment: Are you sure the deallocated instance is the button and not something inside the buttonPressed method? NSZombie should return the kind of the object in question.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the crash log? There should be more than just message sent to deallocated instance 0x8250730.

Comment: 2010-10-27 00:47:28.643 CarTrawler[1537:207] *** -[ReceiptView performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x76cb700

Comment: So it appears to be an instance of ReceiptView that's being deallocated prematurely.  One possibility: are you doing a performSelector:afterDelay: and the view gets dealloced before it fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to retain your button.

It's been a while since you posted this, did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes thats what the problem was.